# counter does not increment or decrement react

Tags: javascript, postgresql

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';


const Quantity = ({ todo }) => {
  const [count, setCount] = useState(+todo.count);
  function decrementCount() {
    setCount(count - 1)
    updateCount(count - 1)
  }

  function incrementCount() {
   setCount(count + 1)
   
   updateCount(count + 1)
 }

  // edit count function 

  const updateCount = async (newCount)  => {
    console.log("this is the newCount", newCount)  

  
  try {
     const body = { "newCount" : newCount}
     const response = await fetch(
      `http://localhost:5000/todos/${todo.todo_id}`,
       {
         method: "PUT",
         headers: { "Content-Type": "application/json" },
         body: JSON.stringify(body)
       }
     );
    
  

     window.location = "/";
    } catch (err) {
      console.error(err.message);
       
    }
   }


 return (
  <>
    <button onClick={() => decrementCount(todo.todo_id)}>-</button>
    <span>{count}</span>
    <button onClick= {() => incrementCount(todo.todo_id)}>+</button>
    </> 
  )
  }
  

export default Quantity;
```

I have created a counter app, however I am unable to get the incrementer and decrementer to work correctly, I have tried so many different things. Currently, whenever I change the count, the "items" in the description column gets deleted. I do not understand how this is happening. I have my current folder for this project on my github under fruitlist version 2 on my github

Comment: In your component return logic, you have passed `todo.todo_id` to decrement and increment function. Is that correct? You should set it to `count` i.e. your state variable. Because you are updating quantity using `count` state variable.

Comment: I have changed the "count" in the return statements, and its working however its not getting transfered over to my database. Do I need to change something in the try, catch statement? I have used postman and my routes are working correctly.

Comment: Do you see any error in developer tool's console? Have you enabled CORS?

Comment: Yes I get an error "index.js:1 Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'id')"

Comment: It's not possible to tell anything like this. If you could update your code on git or codesandbox, I can take a look.

Comment: I have update my code on github, it is fruit list version two, thank you very much for your help!!!!

Comment: Please share the link. I cannot find it.

Comment: https://github.com/TinkerCoding/Fruit-List-Second-Version

Answer (score 0):

The issue was with your update function in `index.js`. Here is the updated code:

```
 app.put("/todos/:id", async (req, res) => {
     try {
         const { id } = req.params;
-        const { description } = req.body;
+        const { newCount } = req.body;
         const updateTodo = await pool.query(
-            "UPDATE todo SET description = $1 WHERE todo_id = $2",
-            [description, id]
+            "UPDATE todo SET count = $1 WHERE todo_id = $2",
+            [newCount, id]
         );
```