# I am unable to update my column in my postgresql database

Tags: javascript, postgresql

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';


const Quantity = ({ todo }) => {
  const [count, setCount] = useState(+todo.count);
  function decrementCount() {
    setCount(count - 1)
    updateCount(count - 1)
  }

  function incrementCount() {    
   setCount(count + 1)
   updateCount(count + 1)
 }

  // edit count function 

  const updateCount = async (newCount)  => {
    console.log("this is the newCount", newCount)  

  
  try {
     const body = { "newCount" : newCount}
     const response = await fetch(
      `http://localhost:5000/todos/${todo.todo.id}`,
       {
         method: "PUT",
         headers: { "Content-Type": "application/json" },
         body: JSON.stringify(body)
       }
     );
    
  

     window.location = "/";
    } catch (err) {
      console.error(err.message);
       
    }
   }


 return (
  <>
    <button onClick={() => decrementCount(count)}>-</button>
    <span>{count}</span>
    <button onClick= {() => incrementCount(count)}>+</button>
    </> 
  )
  }
  

export default Quantity;
```

I am unable to get my counter app to update the "count" column in my postgresql table, any suggestions? Should I change todo.todo.id? or should I change count in regards to the onclick in the return statement?

Comment: Please do not post the same question with slightly different title. How does this differ from [your other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69231215/counter-does-increment-or-decrement). If you need a quick answer then perhaps you need to look elsewhere. SO Community members will assist you with your issues, but everyone volunteers their time and effort, knowledge. But we do have lives outside of SO. Please be patient.  If you feel this is actually different, then *How so?*

Comment: First time using stack overflow, I 'm sorry